# Interact with a file which is load with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I put my navbar in a separated file to avoid duplicate the HTML code of this. 
So, I include my navbar with

```
$("#includeNavbar").load("/navbar.html");
```

But I want to edit the navbar to put an active tab (bootstrap).
I would like to do something like it :

```
$(function() {
            $("#includeNavbar").load("/navbar.html");
            $("#includeNavbar>li").each(function(){
                if($(this).text() == "CV"){
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                }
            });
        });
```

But it doesn't work... Some help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to interact with the file, you must wait until it loads first. The [JQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function has a 2nd argument which is a callback function. The following utilizes that callback and should fire once the page is fully loaded:

```
$(function() {
    $("#includeNavbar").load("/navbar.html", function() {
        $("#includeNavbar>li").each(function(){
            if($(this).text() == "CV"){
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to do it in complete callback since it is loaded asynchronously. You can use filter to..

```
$("#includeNavbar").load("/navbar.html", function() {
    $(this).find('li').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == "CV"
    }).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: It works too, but I don't understand exactly how it works, I'll use it when I'll be better with JQuery... Thanks too !

Comment: If one of these is the answer to your question, you should mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code, try it:

```
$("#includeNavbar").load("/navbar.html", function(){
     $("#includeNavbar li").each(function(){
         if($(this).text() == "CV"){
            $(this).addClass("active");
         }
     });
});
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in the callback like this :

```
$("#includeNavbar").load("/navbar.html",function(){
    $("#includeNavbar>li").each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == "CV"){
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

This will be called after elements loading